# How can i store the byte array of bitmap image from a web service locally using html5

Tags: javascript, html, caching, local-storage, cache-manifest

I have a web service which will return a bitmap image as byte array. I want to store it locally in client side browser. Which HTML5 feature can I use, Cache manifest or local storage? I heard local storage has a limit of 5MB depending on browsers. And my images are having large sizes probably 8MB or more. So what I have to do??

Anyone please help me with sample code. I am new to HTML5 and javascript.